# How to pass variables between Terragrunt workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, terragrunt

I'm new to terragrunt and trying to figure how to pass variables between modules. I'm following terragrunt documentation [here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#passing-outputs-between-modules) yet no luck and fails with error:

```
apps tg run-all plan    
INFO[0000] The stack at /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps will be processed in the following order for command plan:
Group 1
- Module /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/networks-vpc
- Module /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/sri-s3-bucket

Group 2
- Module /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/ec2-amz-lnx
 

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

module.vpc.aws_vpc.vpc: Refreshing state... [id=vpc-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_internet_gateway.igw: Refreshing state... [id=igw-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_subnet.public_subnet_a: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table.private_b: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table.public_b: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private_subnet_b: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table.public_a: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_subnet.public_subnet_b: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table.private_a: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private_subnet_a: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_security_group.sri_sg1: Refreshing state... [id=sg-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route.r_a0: Refreshing state... [id=r-rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route.r_b0: Refreshing state... [id=r-rtb-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_security_group_rule.sri_sg1_ingress_rule1: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_security_group_rule.sri_sg1_egress_rule1: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_security_group_rule.sri_sg1_ingress_rule3: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_security_group_rule.sri_sg1_ingress_rule2: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.public_b: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.private_a: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.public_a: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-xxx]
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.private_b: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-xxx]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
ERRO[0008] Module /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/ec2-amz-lnx has finished with an error: /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/networks-vpc/terragrunt.hcl is a dependency of /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/ec2-amz-lnx/terragrunt.hcl but detected no outputs. Either the target module has not been applied yet, or the module has no outputs. If this is expected, set the skip_outputs flag to true on the dependency block.  prefix=[/Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/ec2-amz-lnx] 
ERRO[0008] 1 error occurred:
        * /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/networks-vpc/terragrunt.hcl is a dependency of /Users/xxx/sri/aws/Infrastructure/apps/ec2-amz-lnx/terragrunt.hcl but detected no outputs. Either the target module has not been applied yet, or the module has no outputs. If this is expected, set the skip_outputs flag to true on the dependency block.
 
ERRO[0008] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

```
My Folder structure:

aws tree
.
├── Infrastructure
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── ec2-amz-lnx
│   │   │   ├── graph.svg
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   │   ├── providers.tf
│   │   │   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   ├── variables.tf
│   │   │   └── versions.tf
│   │   ├── graph.svg
│   │   ├── networks-vpc
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   │   ├── providers.tf
│   │   │   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   ├── variables.tf
│   │   │   └── versions.tf
│   │   ├── sri-s3-bucket
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   │   ├── providers.tf
│   │   │   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   ├── variables.tf
│   │   │   ├── versions.tf
│   │   │   └── website
│   │   │       └── index.html
│   │   └── website-s3
│   ├── binaries
│   │   ├── darwin
│   │   │   ├── terraform
│   │   │   └── terragrunt
│   │   ├── linux
│   │   │   ├── terraform
│   │   │   └── terragrunt
│   │   └── windows
│   │       ├── terraform.exe
│   │       └── terragrunt.exe
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── ap-southeast-2
│   │   │   ├── npe
│   │   │   │   ├── apps
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ec2-amz-lnx.tfvars
│   │   │   │   │   ├── networks-vpc.tfvars
│   │   │   │   │   └── s3.tfvars
│   │   │   │   └── environment.hcl
│   │   │   └── prod
│   │   └── us-east-2
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── ec2
│   │   │   ├── data.tf
│   │   │   ├── files
│   │   │   │   └── user_data_lx_amazon.tpl
│   │   │   ├── iam.tf
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   │   └── variables.tf
│   │   ├── s3
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   │   └── variables.tf
│   │   └── vpc
│   │       ├── main.tf
│   │       ├── outputs.tf
│   │       └── variables.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── test.jpg
```

So I have written terraform modules for vpc, ec2, s3 locally under module folder, that are used by apps(workspaces)and configs/tfvars for environment based on region and environment as shown above.

As you can see above the terragrunt has put networks-vpc in Group 1 and ec2-amz-lnx in Group 2. I've made sure I've declared outputs in VPC(as below)

```
Outputs:

SecurityGroupID = "sg-xxx"
private_subs = {
  "private_subnet_a" = "subnet-xxx"
  "private_subnet_b" = "subnet-xxx"
}
public_subs = "subnet-xxx"
vpc_id = "vpc-xxx"
```

In the ec2-amz-lnx folder, I've created terragrunt.hcl file with following:

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

dependency "shared_infra" {
  config_path = "../networks-vpc"
  # mock_outputs = {
  #   public_subs = "subnet-xxx"
  # }
}

dependencies {
  paths = ["../networks-vpc"]
}

inputs = {
  public_subs = dependency.shared_infra.outputs.public_subs
}
```

and In ec2-amz-lnx, I'm passing public_subs value like below:

```
module "ec2" {
  source = "../../modules/ec2"
  vpc_public_subnet_id = public_subs
  instance_type_lx      = var.instance_type_lx_value
  security_group_ids     = var.security_group_ids_value
  ec2keypair_name     = var.ec2keypair_name_value
  instance_count            = var.instance_count_value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i ve spent some time digging with terrgarunt.

as for the error **"Either the target module has not been applied yet, or the module has no outputs. If this is expected, set the skip_outp..."**

The problem with the teragrunt is that :
if you have module A and module B and  module B depends on module A then ==> you must deploy module B and only after that you can deploy module A. Otherwise terragrunt cant find outputs (variables) from module A to pass them to module B. so you can not deploy module A and module B at one step. You need two separate  steps.
Oh yeah.. "mock outputs" doesnt solve the problem.

It makes terragrunt kind of useless for now.

pure terraform doesnt have sush problem.

Comment: You can set Terragrunt dependencies with the "dependency" configuration; see https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#dependency